# Where to put your websocket in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have been trying to use socket.io with react for some time and I still don't know where to initiate `socket = io(endpoint)`. In most tutorials I have seen, they seem to put it at the **component level** (below the app level. I assume it disconnects whenever you switch routes and the component unmounts). But what if you want to listen to some events consistently regardless of which route you navigate to in your app? Here is what I mean:

```
let socket 

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io(endpoint)
    socket.on('Application wide event', callback)
  }, []) 
}
```

Do you then pass the socket via props? I have tried this approach and sometimes the child componenets wants to emit an event immediately on mount even before the App socket can be successfully created and thus throws an error. Perhaps something like this? :

```
/* socket initialization here */
const App = () => {}
```

What is the conventional practice?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem like yours that I need to listen to some events consistently regardless of which route you navigate to in my app. I manage to do it by initialized the socket on the top level component outside rendering function and exported it, so when I need to emit or listen to a socket I will just import it.

```
/* socket initialization here */
socket = io(endpoint);

const App = () => {
    //return <Routes>...</Routes>
}

export default App;
export {socket};
```

This will lead to socket initialized once so the component that needs it can fire an emit or listen to it immediately.

and to use it:

```
import {socket} from "/App";

const OtherComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("Application wide event", callback)
        return () => {
            socket.off("Application wide event");
        }
    }, [])
}
```

I still wondering if this is a conventional practice but it works on me, I will follow this question, maybe someone knows a better conventional practice.