# Why is my socket.io event listener works properly on a UI component but doesn't work on the other in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks, ionic-react

I have a weird bug that I'm trying to solve (or maybe I made it weird because I'm new to React). I'm using React and TypeScript to build an app that will allows me to subscribe to certain topics in order to receive values and show me in the UI in real time.

Briefly, I have an array containing topics and I'm looping through this array to dynamically create UI elements:

```
{selectedTopics.map((topic: any, idx: number) =>
        < Slider key={idx}
          topic={topic}
          socket={socket} // socket.on is working on this component
          selectedTopics={selectedTopics}
          setSelectedTopics={(topics: any) => setSelectedTopics(topics)}

        />)
      }
       <CustomComponent socket={socket} /> // socket.on is not working on this component
```

As you can see I'm creating a global socket connection in my root app and passing it to children as prop. Then, I'm calling `props.socket.on('subscribe', callback);` In the child component.

Here is my code for the child component (Slider):

```
const Slider: React.FC<{
  socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;
  topic: any;
  selectedTopics: any;
  setSelectedTopics: any;
}> = (props) => {

  const [realTimeValue, setRealTimeValue] = useState<string>("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [subscribed, setSubscribed] = useState<boolean>(false);

  
  const onSubscribe = (topic: any) => {
    
    props.socket.on("onSubscribe", (data: any) => {

     
        const name = data.Name;
        const payload = data.Value;

        console.log(`received response with name: ${name} and payload: ${payload}`);
      if (topic.name === name) {
        console.log(`topic received= ${name} correspond to tpic name = ${topic.name}`);
        setSubscribed(true);
        setRealTimeValue(payload);
        setLoading(false);

      }
      else {

        console.log(`received topic = ${name} but current was ${topic.name} `);
      }
      
      

    });
  }

  const subscribe = (topic: any) => {
    /* I'm invoking this function with a click button. So when the user clicks, then this function will be triggered.

    */
    const req = {
          subscribe: topic.Topic,
        }
     
    props.socket.emit('subscribe', req);
    setLoading(true);
    onSubscribe(topic);


  }
.
.
.
```

As you can see, I'm doing this because I need to send the event to the server where I specify the topic name in order to say to the server, hey I want to subscribe this specific topic. I don't know if this is the best approach since I'm calling the same event and same callback function for all UI components.

This works perfectly, this is not my issue. My issue is I'm passing this global socket object also to the next UI component, which is the `CustomComponent`. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { IonLabel} from '@ionic/react';

const Custom: React.FC<{
  socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;
}> = (props) => {

  const [temp, setTemp] = useState("");


  const handle = (data: any) => {
        console.log(`**received ${data}`);
      setTemp("received");
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    
    console.log("useEffect called ..")
    console.log(`height: ${window.innerHeight} | width: ${window.innerWidth}`);
    
    props.socket.on('onCustom', handle);
    
  }, []) // I tried passing temp, setTemp and props.socket in the dependencies array but nothing worked. However, this works when I pass the handle function in the dep array or not pass any array at all. But not quite as expected because it renders many times until my app freezes.




  return (
        <IonLabel>{temp}</IonLabel>
  );
};

export default Custom;
```

As you can see, I'm using `useEffect` hook to call `socket.on` when the component mounts, since I want it to run when the component mounts and not get triggered by a button like in the Slider component.

Now this does not work and I'm not able to consume the messages sent from the server. It's like my `props.socket.on` is not working, which means that it is not listening on the incoming response from the server. Surprisingly, this works when I don't pass an array dependency at all or when I pass the handle function in the dependency array. However, this renders thousand times per second and after a while the app freezes and I can't do anything.

### Edit

I'm creating my socket instance outside the app component so that it will not render all the time. I don't know if this is the appropriate way to do it. So I have something like this:

```
const socket = socketIOClient(serverHost);

const App: React.FC = () => {
.
.
.
.
```

As you can see I'm creating the socket outside and them I'm using it in the app component by passing it to the children components.

Comment: Does the onCustom event needs any condition for it to be created? Have you tried putting the `socket.on` outside the useEffect?

Comment: @TungPham I did tried that and it worked but as I said, If I do that then I receive the response not only one time but instead 9 times in a row. To explain more what I mean, If I open the browser and go to console, I can see that I receive the message from server but not only one time, instead the first time 3 times in a row and then 9 and then 12 etc... until the app freezes and I can't do nothing. Do you know what I mean? The same thing happens if I use useEffect and pass the handle function in the array as a second argument or not passing an array at all. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Since the component is rerendering a lot, it creates a new instance of onCustom event handler every single time. What I did in the past was to create a context to store all the Websocket configurations and then import and use it in the react component since that way you can avoid situations like this. Another way I can think of is because your component is being rerendered so much, you can move the onCustom handler to another component that is being rendered less than this one. However, I would go with separating all the socket.io config and event handler from the component.

Comment: Hope this link would help: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-web-sockets-in-your-reactredux-app. In there they basically declare and separate all the WS config like event handler and event register to another context file. Then they import and use that for later.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of how can I create a context to store all websocket configs? I didn't get the idea

Comment: I just commented so it takes a little time to appears but I hope that link can help you get a better idea

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work. Try to move the `handle` function inside `useEffect` callback and add the `temp` in the depedency:

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    console.log("useEffect called ..")
    console.log(`height: ${window.innerHeight} | width: ${window.innerWidth}`);
    
    props.socket.on('onCustom', (data: any) => {
        console.log(`**received ${data}`);
        setTemp("received");
    });
    
}, [temp])
```

Comment: may I know where you declared the main socket instance? Is it outside of a rendering component?

Comment: yes the socket instance is outside of the app component. Like directly after the import statements, I declared the socket client instance and then used it inside the app component.

Comment: ok, how about instead of passing the socket instance as props export it from app component, we will try to avoid the rerendering... export {socket}.. then import it n your CustomComponent component .. hope it works :)

Comment: I edited my question to show you how I'm doing it. How can I export it from app component ? can you show me an example. If I declared it in the app then I don't need to export it becaues app is my root or parent component and all others are children so I can pass it as a prop

Comment: something like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63749721/where-to-put-your-websocket-in-react/63750181#63750181). I wonder why its firing many times when you don't place dep on useEffect.. that means your server emit to client many times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222110/discussion-between-chanandrei-and-basilisk).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Angular,
The problem was because the chatSocketService provider was a submodule
To correct I put the service which extend the socket in the main module of the project